# time series forecasting: 'start' value not changed

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I need to obtain the performance of three-month mean naive time series forecast for the validation set as follows:

```
library(fpp2)
library(forecast)
data(ausbeer)
train1 <- window(ausbeer, start = c(1956,1), end = c(2004,4))
valid1 <- window(ausbeer, start = c(2005,1), end = c(2007,4))
test1 <- window(ausbeer, start = c(2008,1))
# Calculate three-month mean
naive3 <- zoo::rollmean(train1, 3, align="right")
accuracy(naive3, valid1, h=1)[,1:5]
```

However, the error is:

```
Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'
In addition: Warning message:
In window.default(x, ...) : 'start' value not changed
```

I am allowed just to use library(forecast), library(timeSeries), and library(astsa).

Answer (score 0):

The `naive3` time series finishes in 2004 Q4 and the `valid1` time series starts in 2005 Q1. So `accuracy()` can't find any overlapping observations to compare.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please let me know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I just need to use 3 days rolling mean. Other functions might be ok.